# Example of materials with 21 independant coefficients in linear elasticity?

Tags: classical-mechanics, elasticity

By definition of linear elasticity, the strain et stress tensors are related:
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\sigma}=\mathbf{C}:\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}
\end{equation}
and because of minor and major symmetries, $\mathbf{C}$ has *at most* 21 independent coefficients (see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_elasticity)).

Are there materials whose mechanical description really requires 21 independent coefficients? Triclinic crystals seem to be such an example, but it's rather obscure to me (probably because it's a small scale material).

Comment: I don't know for sure so I can't answer. However, if triclinic crystals are an example, then [there is at least one explosive](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/prep.200800225/abstract) that would be. However, I know from implementing a structural solver (for explosives) that even if they are not all independent, one must often write code *as if they were* because the symmetric terms are different for each material and orientation.

Comment: @tpg2114 TY for your answer. Maybe you have to consider all of them so that the users can enter the coefficients corresponding to their experiments?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly why I need to have them generalized like that. I personally have not simulated something with all 21 coefficients, but I have simulated ones with different symmetries so I have entered all 21 at some point. If that makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

Albite is one example of a triclinic material for which all twenty-one elasticity constants have been calculated.